# Networkx 2.1: equivalent code for node index

Tags: python, networkx

I have an old Networkx script that uses G.nodes().index(nnn) and need to run in Networkx 2.1. From the documentation is not clear how to convert or what is the equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for index of node `nnn` in the adjacency matrix ? If that is the case then you can simply look up the index of  `nnn` in the list created by `G.nodes()`. The function documentation of the function [adjacency_matrix(G, nodelist,weight)](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-2.1/reference/generated/networkx.linalg.graphmatrix.adjacency_matrix.html#networkx.linalg.graphmatrix.adjacency_matrix) specifies how the order of nodes is taken for adjacency matrix

> **nodelist : list, optional**
>
> The rows and columns are ordered according to the nodes in nodelist. If nodelist is None, then the ordering is produced by
>   G.nodes().

So I think the following code should work for you

```
nodes_list = list(G.nodes())
nodes_list.index(nnn)
```